# why htaccess redirect even if folder exist?

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I have .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
AddType text/css .css
```

Jquery Ajax send requests to mysite.com/ajax/. Ajax folder exist, but htaccess redirects.
Don't know where is the problem.

Comment: check folder name case if it is ajax of Ajax?

Comment: not. names are equal ajax

Comment: resolved! there was problem with index.php in ajax/folder there was included config.php which redirects to main page

Answer (score 0):

solved! there was problem with index.php in ajax/folder there was included config.php which redirects to main page